# users router not working in node.js. Getting 404 even when route is defined

Tags: node.js

The `app.js` has the following statements

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

In the `routes` directory, there are two files

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
let index = require('../controllers/index');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', index.index);

module.exports = router;
```

and

users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('users', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My expectation is that if the route is `/`, I should see view corresponding to `router.get('/', index.index);` and if the route is `/users`, I should see view corresponding to `res.render('users', { title: 'Express' });`.

However, I get `404` for `/users`.

Strangely, if I add `/users` rule in `index.js`, the route works

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
let index = require('../controllers/index');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', index.index);
router.get('/users', index.user); <-- this resolves

module.exports = router;
```

Why is the application not picking the route defined in `users.js` in route directory.

Comment: seems I found the answer as soon as I submitted the question. The rule for resolving `/users` is already in `app.use('/users', usersRouter);`. `users.js` in `routes` should have a rule for `/` to resolve `/users` path. In its current form, it resolves `/users/users`.

Comment: Just do `app.use(usersRouter)` instead of mounting it to another path